# Couchdb -> Query first databse that can interface with second database

Tags: database, data-binding, couchdb

We are working on arduino, which the rfid reader that is currently taking in numbers like "1234" when the rfid tag is being scanned.

When we scanned the rfid tag, it will be entered into couchdb, which is our database that we have created.

Our question is, we would want to associate a name with the unique number "1234" And this association should be stored in a database so that

Database(1); to store patients info
Database(2); that logs the unique number

we would like it that,

```
   1 : we scan the tag, "1234"
   2. : the system queries the database(1) for "1234"
   3. : the query replies "1234" with the patient name for example "Jack" 
   4. : post in database (2) patient name & time
```

problem is how we can query the database1 for info to be input into database2

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? The database can't automatically "interface" with a second database. Could you please add some code that would help explain what you've tried?

Comment: With your design: In DB(x) create a view that returns a key that can be used to correlate data in DB(y). So either the RFID value exists in both places or some patient key does.